# Exchanger server 2010 signature save error

Tags: windows-server-2008, 64-bit, exchange-2010, email

I have Exchange Server 2010 on windows 2008 server 64bit machine.

When any of our users want to save settings or signature, I get following error:

[image]

How can I fix this?

**EDIT**

the problem i found is with binding of second Port with https in IIS, if i remove the binding every thing work fine,

how can i solve this binding issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That picture doesn't give much to go on, but it looks like you've gone into Outlook Web App and then to Options, taking you to the Exchange Control Panel (ECP).

As a first measure (if you're not already), try it in Internet Explorer 7 or higher rather than some other browser or an older version of Internet Explorer.

Next, check all your Exchange services are running by running the `Test-ServiceHealth` cmdlet and looking for any of your roles where the `RequiredServicesRunning` property is *False*. If so, you'll get a list of services not running in the `ServicesNotRunning` property. Start all of these with the cmdlet `Start-Service` (i.e `Start-Service MSExchangeAB`). You could always try bouncing IIS, just for good measure (`iisreset /noforce`).

Are you able to update the signature from the shell? Try running `Set-MailboxMessageConfiguration SomeMailbox -AutoAddSignature $true -SignatureHtml 'Testing signature from shell'` - that will enable the signature and populate it with a value (just to test it's not fundamentally broken). Refresh the ECP and see if that appears in your signature box.

**Edit**
You say you changed the port OWA is on - did you tell Exchange you did this by updating the internal and external URLs of OWA and ECP? This is under the Server Configuration => Client Access section in the Exchange management console.

Comment: Dear Ben
Thanks for reply.

1. i try Test-ServiceHealth all services are running properly.
2. i try to set signature from Shell, its saving signature properly.

but once in IE i goto options page, i use to get above error on all settings tabs, also if i chnage the signate and try to save i also get above error.

Thanks

Comment: Have you changed any IIS settings, or do you host other websites on that server?

Comment: Thanks for reply.        

i just chnage the port for owa in IIS7
other settings are not chnaged and no other host is hosted on server..

Comment: Please see Edit in updated answer

Comment: Dear Ben, thanks for your reply but problem is still same even i chnage the internal and external urls.
see even if i access the owa on original settings without port chnage, i got same error....

Comment: Dear Ben, Please look at edit in question...

Comment: Can I ask why you want more than 1 binding?